# How to use google distance matrix api with python multi origins to multi destinations

Tags: python, google-distancematrix-api

How to calculate google distance matrix API with Python from multi origins to multi destinations
Here are my codes, something is wrong with the outer loop. Would you help me to fix it?

```
import googlemaps
import csv
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='My_google_distance_KEY')
count1 = 1
count2 = 1
Name_index = 2
station_index = 14
infile1 = open('C:\Users\Thinkpad\Documents\Python Scripts\Input\Metro1.csv', 'r')
infile2 = open('C:\Users\Thinkpad\Documents\Python Scripts\Input\Metro2.csv', 'r')
output1 = open('C:\Users\Thinkpad\Documents\Python Scripts\Output\M_distance.csv', 'w')
reader1 = csv.reader(infile1)
reader2 = csv.reader(infile2)
writer1 = csv.writer(output1)
for row in list(reader1)[count1:]:
    Name1 = row[Name_index]
    Location1 = row[station_index]
    print(Location1)
    for row in list(reader2)[count2:]:
        Location2 = row[station_index]
        Name2 = row[Name_index]
        my_distance = gmaps.distance_matrix(Location1, Location2, mode='transit', language=None, avoid=None, units=None,
                                        departure_time='1475925955', arrival_time=None,
                                        transit_routing_preference=None)
        print(my_distance)
        if my_distance['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['status'] != 'ZERO_RESULTS':
            Duration = my_distance['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value']
        else:
            Duration = 10000000
        if my_distance['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['status'] != 'ZERO_RESULTS':
            Distance = my_distance['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value']
        else:
            Distance = 10000000
        writer1.writerow((Name1, Name2, Duration, Distance,))
```

And the results are followed:

```
39.72327906 ,   116.1253664
{u'status': u'OK', u'rows': [{u'elements': [{u'duration': {u'text': u'1 min', u'value': 0}, u'distance': {u'text': u'1 m', u'value': 0}, u'status': u'OK'}]}], u'origin_addresses': [u'55 Chang Hong Xi Lu, Fangshan Qu, Beijing Shi, China'], u'destination_addresses': [u'55 Chang Hong Xi Lu, Fangshan Qu, Beijing Shi, China']}
{u'status': u'OK', u'rows': [{u'elements': [{u'duration': {u'text': u'17 mins', u'value': 1029}, u'distance': {u'text': u'1.4 km', u'value': 1376}, u'status': u'OK'}]}], u'origin_addresses': [u'55 Chang Hong Xi Lu, Fangshan Qu, Beijing Shi, China'], u'destination_addresses': [u'Chang Hong Xi Lu, Fangshan Qu, Beijing Shi, China, 102401']}
{u'status': u'OK', u'rows': [{u'elements': [{u'duration': {u'text': u'22 mins', u'value': 1327}, u'distance': {u'text': u'2.9 km', u'value': 2871}, u'status': u'OK'}]}], u'origin_addresses': [u'55 Chang Hong Xi Lu, Fangshan Qu, Beijing Shi, China'], u'destination_addresses': [u'9 Chang Hong Dong Lu, Fangshan Qu, Beijing Shi, China, 102401']}
{u'status': u'OK', u'rows': [{u'elements': [{u'duration': {u'text': u'23 mins', u'value': 1369}, u'distance': {u'text': u'4.4 km', u'value': 4436}, u'status': u'OK'}]}], u'origin_addresses': [u'55 Chang Hong Xi Lu, Fangshan Qu, Beijing Shi, China'], u'destination_addresses': [u'Chang Hong Dong Lu, Fangshan Qu, Beijing Shi, China']}
{u'status': u'OK', u'rows': [{u'elements': [{u'duration': {u'text': u'25 mins', u'value': 1500}, u'distance': {u'text': u'5.6 km', u'value': 5616}, u'status': u'OK'}]}], u'origin_addresses': [u'55 Chang Hong Xi Lu, Fangshan Qu, Beijing Shi, China'], u'destination_addresses': [u'Dong Huan Lu, Fangshan Qu, Beijing Shi, China']}
39.72328283 ,   116.1408152
39.72325725 ,   116.1562973
39.7232697  ,   116.1764466
39.729987   ,   116.183392
```

It should be 5*5 lines of distances printing. right now it is only 5 lines.

If possible, would you help me to fix it?

Best,
Guowei

Comment: At first glance it looks like the indentation is wrong, so that instead of an inner and outer loop you have two outer loops. Try increasing the indentation of everything starting with "for row in list(reader2)[count2:]:"

Comment: Thank you, @SohierDane, the original codes are with several indentations starting with "for row in list(reader2)[count2:]:". It was wrongly posted on the website. However, I have added the indentations. Still, the code doesn't work.